# Past tense of "greenlight"

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses, past-tense

Is it greenlighted or greenlit? Is there a correct one or are both acceptable?

Comment: I've seen "greenlighted".  Don't recall seeing "greenlit" (which might be confused for "green literature").

Comment: When an irregular noun or verb is reified into a fixed phrase or compound, it becomes regular. It's the Toronto Maple Leafs, for instance, not *Maple Leaves; the name has nothing to do with leaves. As for _greenlight_, it's a new word, so it'll take a century or so to settle down. But whatever the past tense winds up as, does anybody think the past participle can be _greenlit_?  E.g, *_He has greenlit more movies than anybody else_

Comment: I would say "greenlighted" personally. The term seems to be derived from traffic lights or indicator lights and "greenlit" sounds more like "illuminated with green light" than "showed the green light" which, I believe to be the intention.

Comment: Probably related to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21198) answer (about another compound of ‘lit’/‘lighted’).  My impression was that ‘-lighted’ was more of a US form, and ‘-lit’ was more common here in the UK — but the figures don't seem to bear that out.

Answer (score 4):

Both are in use, with *greenlit* being slightly more common than *greenlighted* according to COCA (32 vs 21 hits).

[See for yourself](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) by searching for `greenli*`.

Answer (score 2):

Either use is acceptable:   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/greenlight)

> tr.v. greenlighted or greenlit

As in:

> "[He] commissioned the pilot that became 'Captain Kangaroo' and
>   greenlighted the series" (Variety).

or

> 1992   Premiere Feb. 47/2   There he green-lit both The Silence of the
>   Lambs and The Addams Family.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wiktionary, both are acceptable: [greenlight](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/greenlight).

[Google n-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=greenlighted%2Cgreenlit&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgreenlighted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreenlit%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgreenlighted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreenlit%3B%2Cc0) shows that by 2008 (when the data ends), *greenlighted* was used about 2.3 times as often as *greenlit*.

Answer (score 0):

Probably is "Greenlighted"

reference: 
So far three directors have greenlighted the project.

This meaning is based on one submitted to the Open Dictionary by: Boris Marchenko from Russian Federation on 30/08/2015

Comment: Can you provide a link?