# Which past tense of "to light" should I use here?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, past-tense, ed-vs-t

I know that there are two ways to form the past tense of *to light* (i.e. lit/lighted). Which one is appropriate for the sentence below?

> His thoughts *lighted* our way.

or

> His thoughts *lit* our way.

Comment: For reference: http://www.englishrules.com/writing/2006/lit-and-lighted/

Comment: This question is easily answered by a dictionary: *verb (past lit /lɪt/; past participle lit or lighted)*.  If the question was "why are there two different past participles for some verbs?", we are happy to answer that (we have already).

Comment: Here is the thing that I suspect you are missing. english is not my native tongue. I speak and write pretty well though. But sometimes I may miss the nuances of the language. When I googled for lit-lighted I could not find an answer that satisfied me. The worry I had was if these two used for different contexts. For example maybe lit was used for actualy putting something on fire and lighted in a more allegorical way. That is why I gave the example His thoughts lit/lighted our way instead of I lit/lighted a candle.

Comment: [Why do some words have two past tense forms (e.g. “dreamed” vs. “dreamt”)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/why-do-some-words-have-two-past-tense-forms-e-g-dreamed-vs-dreamt)

Comment: We understand that many users here are *not* native speakers. However, asking for the past participle of a verb is fairly general reference. It adds a lot of research to a question if you say "I found that these are both past participles. Are they correct in different situations?"

Comment: I did all this with a simple question. I did not want to ask a 250 word question that no one would read. A deep question does not have  to be 250 words. By using thoughts instead of a candle in the example I accomplished what I had in mind. If you are not sure, ask before judging.

Comment: ykg: Your question was clear. If you want to know when to use which one, say so.

Comment: Anyone who tries to make a distinction is either a nit picker or somebody trying to sound intelligent.

Comment: @JohnWright trying to sound intelligent is much better than the alternative, all else being equal. Indeed, that sounds like a perfectly good reason to learn of any distinction they might have (though I do not find evidence that there is any such distinction, in actual fact).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a feeling that the best word for here is "lighted". "Lighted" is used more when referring to something illuminating another.

When generally referring to a source of light that brightens up the room, "lighted" is preferred:

> The lantern lighted the whole room.

"Lit" is generally more used for "setting on fire" :

> He lit the paper and threw it in the bin.
>   The little spark lit the straw, and the whole barn burned down.

Also,"lit" has an alternative meaning:

> Slang . under the influence of liquor or narcotics; intoxicated (usually followed by up ).

Thus, I feel that "lighted" would be best here.

> His thoughts lighted our way.

---

"Light" has two meanings, one meaning "to cause to take fire", and the other "to illuminate".  When referring to "light" in the first sense, the past would be "lit":

> He tried to light his cigar/ He lit his cigar

When referring to "light" in the second sense, "lighted"(often along with "up" is used:

> His words were a light to my future/His words lighted up my future.

Comment: Just for everyone's notice, the OP has changed the question, and it is now a valid question. I am reopening the question.

Comment: Agreed. I had a discussion with the OP, and this seems like a very valid question now.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy. *Lighted* and *lit* are synonymous and can be used in place of each other. There is no rule to use one or the other. Pick either.

Comment: Not yet so, although they're moving towards collapsing into each other.

Answer (score -4):

Lit is British English and lighted is American English, the same thing with dreamt and dreamed respectively.

Comment: Without some authoritative support, this answer is likely to be closed.

Comment: Not only do you have no evidence for this, but it seems unlikely in light of this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lighted+the+fire%3Aeng_us_2012%2Clit+the+fire%3Aeng_us_2012%2Clighted+the+fire%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Clit+the+fire%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clighted%20the%20fire%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clit%20the%20fire%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clighted%20the%20fire%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clit%20the%20fire%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0)