# Plural form of 'schema'

Tags: grammatical-number

**Schema** appears to have two plural forms that are both valid: *schemata* and *schemas*. Are they completely interchangeable; or are there any guidelines on which one is appropriate for particular contexts?

Comment: If anyone is interested in the pronunciation of *schemata*, I asked a question about words with the same ending: [Why does “stigmata” (often) have penult stress?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269732/why-does-stigmata-often-have-penult-stress)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The Greek *schemata* is mostly found in academic writing (e.g. experimental schemata), whereas the anglicized *schemas* is used freely in both technical and more general discourse (e.g. database access schemas).

Comment: This is exactly correct.

Comment: The "competition" for the bounty has just stiffened :)

Comment: @ScotM I just saw nothing wrong with my database schemata ;)

Answer (score 25):

When a word comes into English from another language (or as a coinage using parts from another language) with a countable noun sense, there are two possible approaches to pluralising; to also borrow the plural (hence *criteria* for *criterion*, and *bacteria* for *bacterium*) or using the normal *-s* and similar productions of English plurals (*pianos* or the longer *pianofortes* rather than the Italian *piani* and *pianoforti*).

There's no logical rule that says we can't say "The musicians got sick because the piani were covered with bacteriums", but language exists in a space of rough consensus, and the consensus is that *piani* and *bacteriums* are wrong, while *pianos* and *bacteria* are correct, and we keep using them because that's what everyone else does.

While many words go strongly one way or another, there are several words in English that have both a loan-word plural from the same source as the singular and one produced in the normal *-s* production for English plurals: *radius* with *radii* and *radiuses*, *cactus* with *cacti* and *cactuses*, *virtuoso* with *virtuosi* and *virtuosos*.*

As with things like which spelling became the accepted spelling, whether a coinage or slang word becomes considered "a real world" and so on, it's hard to predict which will happen until a point of consensus is reached at which point one form becomes "just right" and another "just wrong", or alternatively two forms continue to compete for a long time (consider [*lit* and *lighted* competing for 400 years to be the past of *light*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/104015/15770) as an example of the same thing happening with a different case where there can be a comparable split).

There are a few things that can encourage it to go one way or another. The more the average English-speaker who uses the word is to have at least a passing knowledge of the source language, the more likely it is to survive in English (hence Latin and Greek plurals survive more due to their former educational importance). A language that doesn't often have plural forms will often not have that lack of plural form continue into English (hence "two ninjas" is more likely than "two ninja"). Words that are commonly used in the plural will more often keep them (hence *criteria* and *bacteria* survive easily) or even overthrow the singular (*data* is often used as an uncountable or even singular, displacing *datum*).

Contrasting to that, if a word is relatively obscure, then so will its plural be, and people will produce an *-s* plural lacking any other choice.

As a general rule, usages will become more and more "normal" over time, and that includes words with foreign plurals tending to become *-s* plurals.

This ngram would suggest that this has been happening with schemas/schemata:
[image]
Bearing the fallibility of ngrams in mind, it would still seem that *schemata* was the more popular for some time, but *schemas* overtook recently.

Since people use language as those around them use it, use in a particular community may go strongly one way or another, and it could be that this is at play here. The term *schema* comes up often in terms of databases today, and many people using the word in that context would be otherwise unfamiliar with the word (and hence more likely to use a productive than an imported plural). Considering the following, they may be the community that has pushed *schemas* past *schemata*:
[image]

At the same time though, part of the SQL standard is called "SQL/Schemata" and some databases have a view or table called "Schemata" (a table in MySQL and a view in SQL Server and PostgreSQL), which is likely to keep it at least known about in that community.

The opposite pressure used to exist in the XML Schema standard as its documentation seemed to favour *schemata* once, though that community seems to have moved to *schemas*. Still, both exist in current use, including [this announcement](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xmlschema-dev/2005Feb/0007.html) that uses one in one sentence, and the other in the next!

> Are they completely interchangeable;

All the above is a way of arriving at "yes, they are completely interchangeable". While one of the other might be more common in certain contexts, there are none where one is so massively more popular as to make the other seem wrong, or even strange.

> or are there any guidelines on which one is appropriate for particular contexts?

Not really, for that reason. If you're worried then use what others around you are using, but if you just like the look and sound of one more (I personally prefer *schemata*) then by all means do as you will.

---

*There are two other possibilities. One is that people may apply the *wrong* foreign plural rule, e.g. producing *octopi*. Another is that joke plurals may force foreign forms onto plurals that didn't generally use them, and later other people may not get the joke, leading some people to think that *virii* and *penii* are alternatives to, or even more "learned" than, *viruses* and *penises* when those were just jokes.

Comment: Thanks for the humerus ending! No one mentioned conflation with the more normal scheme?

Comment: @ScotM do you think that conflation occurs and has an impact? It's plural is clearly *schemes* which isn't that close to either *schemas* or *schemata* and while it comes from *σχῆμα* it does so via the Latin *schema* (plural *schemae* or *schemæ*) so nor is someone with the origin strong in their mind going to pluralise it similar to *schemata*.

Comment: As a student of Greek, that distinction is apparent to me, but Everyman does not think as deeply about his words. The conflation is an unsubstantiated theory, that I wish I had time to explore!

Comment: The student of Greek knows better. The non-student of Greek either "just knows" that the plural is *schemata* or just sticks an *-s* on the end. The student of English etymology, akin with the student of Latin, knows that *scheme* came to us via mediæval Latin and so not directly analogous anyway.

Comment: @ScotM Incidentally, I have genuinely come across people who didn't realise that *virii* was a joke (and in fairness, since it was a joke among techies and techies were their source of information on computer viruses, why shouldn't they take it in earnest?), and I'm not too sure whether one person honestly thought *penii* was correct or was good at dead-pan.

Comment: I liked your answer too (which imo essentially gives the same answer but with lots of other interesting bits). So I had thought I'd just immediately set up another bounty and give you a bounty each! However, I hadn't realised that once you've set a bounty the next one must be at least double the rep :( That's abit too much for me right at the moment - but you seem quite rep rich, so maybe just the kudos of knowing I'd have given you a bounty will cheer you up? I hope so! Nice answer :)

Comment: Hi! @JonHanna I really enjoyed this answer. I'm not a native English speaker. I had `schemae` in mind, and I just wanted to confirm if it was the correct plural. I didn't even know about `schemata`. So, what happens with `schemae`? is it a correct word in English? Thanks for your thorough answer!

Comment: @Throoze not correct in English. *Schema* is Greek so if you aren't using the English productive plural *schemas* you would use the Greek plural *schemata* (*σχήματα* plural to *σχῆμα*). It does often happen that Greek words come into English via Latin, and there is a Latin word *schema* whose plural is *schemae* or *schemæ*, but of the several senses of *σχῆμα*, that Latin *schema* refers only to a different one than the English *schema* does, so as well as not being the route the word took into English, it also isn't quite the same word. As such *schemae* wouldn't make much sense.