# Irregular past tense confusion with compound noun/verb. More examples?

Tags: verbs, past-tense, past-participles, compounds, irregular

Students of martial arts may be familiar with a *breakfall*, which can (depending on the situation) be treated as a noun or a verb.

I am often amused when speakers, even native English speakers (myself included!), stumble over the past tense because of the double-irregularity. I've heard *breakfalled*, *breakfell*, *brokefall*, and *brokefell* - most try one combination or another and then switch to *did a breakfall*.

I was wondering if people had other examples of this phenomenon, and whether there is a canonically correct past tense form?

*EDIT: Prompted by the discussion, for those interested, a breakfall may be defined as any of several ways of 'receiving' a technique, but in Western parlance most often refers to a method of slapping the ground (mat) just at the moment of impact, when you are thrown. This provides a reactive force and lessens the whole body impact if you are unable to roll out. (See [uke/ukemi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uke_%28martial_arts%29) for the Japanese perspective).*

Comment: you may find this useful http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/why-do-some-words-have-two-past-tense-forms-e-g-dreamed-vs-dreamt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FNYsAios4BsC&pg=PT93&dq=%22on%20lended%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Qo7zUO7jH_Kb1AWJvoC4BQ&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAw) an example of the neologism [*on-lend*](http://www.rusnauka.com/7_NND_2009/Philologia/42834.doc.htm) *(give a loan with money lent from other companies)*...

> ...central bank credit was a major source of finance for banks (**on-lended** at fixed spreads)...

...which illustrates the general principle that verb nelogisms are normally regular. The established pattern over centuries is that irregular verbs are disappearing; so long as the nelogism is genuinely perceived as a "new"  verb (as it probably is with *breakfall, on-lend*), it's automatically treated as a regular verb by default. So just use *breakfalled*.

---

EDIT: I should point out there's no definitive authority specifying how any given verb neologism *will* be conjugated before usage becomes established custom and practice. For example...

Google Books favours [troubleshot](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22troubleshot%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) over [troubleshooted](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22troubleshot%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22troubleshooted%22&oq=%22troubleshooted%22&gs_l=serp.3...3684.5869.0.6375.3.3.0.0.0.0.137.225.2j1.3.0...0.0...1c.1.grLn6vrsaQ8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41018144,d.d2k&fp=100ada7022426c34&biw=1149&bih=864) by about 7:1. But on Google Internet (which I assume represents more widespread *current* usage), the bias is only half that. My guess is that as people get more used to *troubleshoot* as an "independent" verb, they'll increasingly regularise it.

But all "authorities" now seem to agree that for the baseball (ex-)neologism *to fly out* (to hit a fly ball), the "correct" past tense is [flied out](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2010/06/why-dont-we-say-the-batter-flew-out.html) (not *flew out*).

My suggestion for OP to use the regular form is partly based on the fact that I have absolutely no idea what *breakfalling* is, so I make no close connection between the neologism and the component (verbs?) *break* and *fall*. And either or both could be seen as "nouns", which would make me even less inclined to replicate the irregular verb forms.

Comment: In this case I think that due to the presence of two irregular verbs, none of the suggested forms sound quite right when spoken. Perhaps, one just has to accept that _breakfelled_ sounds the least wrong! :)

Comment: @Kyudos: I don't understand your apparent reluctance to go with what is effectively standard practice. True verb neologisms are invariably regular. Read a bit more of that first link in the answer.

Comment: Because, from my experience of this word, there is no standard practice. No one seems happy with the past tense verb form, often switching to the noun form when the verb 'doesn't work'. I can accept that _breakfalled_ is the correct form, but that doesn't make it sound correct.

Comment: @Kyudos: Well, I suppose that "doesn't sound correct" thinking is what makes people revert to *did a breakfall* to avoid the problem. There is no actual right/wrong here, obviously, so perhaps I'd better expand the answer to reflect that.

Comment: "When you read a sentence like "Ryan Braun **flied out** to right, allowing Hart to tag and go to third," does that sound correct, merely tolerable, or downright wrong to you?" (http://throwingthings.blogspot.in/2011/08/alott5ma-grammar-rodeo-national-pastime.html)

Comment: Also, in CS: ;  "Oh, now that is cool - one of my favorite interaction options - unlabeled, **un-flyouted** buttons without icons or anything else..." (cgsociety); "when pane is pinned, it may be **FlyOuted** after doubleclick on the window header" (infragistics); "If fly out button is clicked and then mouseover the MAIN menu, is it possible to hide & close down the **flyouted** menu?" (curse.com)

Comment: @Kris: I don't do martial arts or baseball, so all I can say is Googling [baseball "flied out"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=baseball+%22flied+out%22&oq=baseball+%22flied+out%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.7936974&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) makes it pretty clear that's accepted usage. I'd have thought with OP's *breakfall* people will either get used to the regular form, or they'll avoid using it as a verb in past tense. Having now realised the origin is *verb=break, noun=fall*, I think *brokefall* is far too weird, and *breakfell* clashes with the etymology.

Answer (score 1):

Inflection will mask.

From a simple plain-English speaker's perspective, verb neologisms necessarily need to have regular conjugations so the neologism could be visible.

Among *breakfalled, breakfell, brokefall, and brokefell*, only *breakfalled* contains the neologism in toto.

Related verb, *fell* ("make fall, cause to fall,") pt. *felled*.