# What English words have unique prevocalic forms?

Tags: vowels, word-formation

The indefinite article *a* becomes *an* when it precedes a word beginning with a vowel sound. Similar conventions can be found in *thy* → *thine* and the now-archaic *my* → *mine*.

Aside from these three examples, are there any other words that take on a special form when they proceed a vowel sound?

I'm aware that some people consider *amongst* to be a prevocalic form of *among*, but this usage does not seem to be universal, and furthermore doesn't follow with similar word pairs such as *amid*/*amidst* or *while*/*whilst*.

Comment: I have never heard of the "amongst" thing, do you have a citation for that?

Comment: It's wrong, anyway. That's not the way _amongst_ works, no matter what somebody may have opined. There is also the differential pronunciation (though not spelling) of _the_: /ði/ before vowels /ði'oldhæt/, vs /ðə/ before consonants /ðə'bɪghæt/.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai No definitive source per se, but it's mentioned in http://writingexplained.org/amo and http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66059/170366. http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/02/am also notes, 'Some older grammar guides state that amongst is typically followed by a word starting with a vowel, but this assertion isn’t supported by the evidence of current English as found in the [Oxford English Corpus].'

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "form." It's quite uncommon for words to be spelled differently before vowel sounds; it's somewhat more common for words to be pronounced differently before vowel sounds.

For example, as John Lawler mentions in a comment, people tend to pronounced the definite article *the* as /ði/ before words that start with vowels, but as /ðə/ before words that start with consonants.

Another example, although not at all consistent, is the word *of.* The /v/ in this word can be elided; as far as I can tell, this is more likely to occur before a consonant sound than before a vowel sound. In a small number of lexically-specified phrases, this elision is mandatory and reflected in the spelling (the only examples I can think of at the moment are *jack-o'-lantern* and *o'clock*).

For British English speakers, certain vowel sounds, such as /ɔː/, /ɑː/, /ɜː/, and /ə/, tend to be followed by a "linking r" when they are brought before another vowel.

Comment: _To_ is another example like _the_, alternating between /tə/ and /tʊ/.